# Spring Boot user job/process monitoring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

using Spring 2.0.3
I have a set of Spring Servers which I need to find out if the Spring is processing a request sent to it. Only one of these requests is processed at a time. In this case the request is, depending on options, can cause a good number of code paths to be used. To support the different variations of the starting call there are about 30 different services and some other classes.

I need to be able to send some request to these servers and ask the question: Are you working on one of these requests. The response can be a simply yes or no.

In trying to come up with an approach it kind of seems like the Spring Actuator might be the way to go. However in a least some of the material I have looked at seems like it is at more of a sysadmin type of level.

My question is how to approach this issue? Is the Actuator the best bet to archive what I am looking for, and if not what to do? If possible would like to avoid placing code in each service/class to see what is going on.

thanks

Comment: Here's what I understood: you have a set of web applications running behind a load balancer. and you want to find out which server is processing the given request? Also, what do you mean by `Only one of these requests is processed at a time`? \

Comment: Not exactly. The "worker" Spring Servers are located at random locations. The purpose of the Servers are to run a user invoked job. The jobs are not a web application. In the original design only one of those jobs would be run at a time on one of the servers. So like I have 20 Servers and the Max number of jobs I could run at the same time would be 20. So the goal is to test when the job is done to send another one to the server.

Comment: How are the jobs/requests being 'Sent' ?  The solution will be based that mechanism (event-msg / db-poll / ...etc) - as it's more optimal if the server that accepts a job to ACK the receipt of the job on a common way.

Comment: `The jobs are not a web application`, so the spring web app triggers some script to run the jobs? How does the spring web app knows when the job was finished?

Comment: Based on what I understood so far, you will need a mechanism in each server to know if a job is running on the server and if the earlier job was finished. That way you could establish a web endpoint to return the status. As you mentioned you can define a custom actuator endpoint that checks the status of job and returns `OK/NOK`.

Comment: Jobs are started via a stomp call to a REST API on the workers. The calls contain all of the multitude of options which the job require. The jobs may or may not connect to other systems, may or may not download info from other systems.